# Joomla 1.5 SEF Qcontacts not working

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-sef-urls

I am working with a joomla site and I installed a component named qcontacts. It works perfectly, but when I enable sef in joomla I get:
[image: warning]

All the other menus in the site work properly with seo enabled with com_content, the problem is only with qcontancts. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actualy commented out from "components/com_content/router.php" the following lines

```
//require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php');
//require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'helpers'.DS.'query.php');
//require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'helpers'.DS.'route.php');
```

and everything seems to be working fine with sef. I am not sure if i did the correct thing or if i have any sideefects in the futre. But for now everything seems to be working.